# No Sensors found в Ubuntu 20.04 в Windows

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu

В Windows 10 можно установить эмулятор Linux, а именно устанавливается Ubuntu 20.04. При попытке ввести sensors система пишет "no sensors found". При sudo sensors-detect пишет "No i2c device files found."
При sudo modprobe i2c-sensor выдает modprobe: FATAL: Module i2c-sensor not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-19041-Microsoft

Что делать?
Спасибо.

Comment: *"эмулятор"* - какой именно

Comment: Логика мне подсказывает, что в эмуляторе и в самом деле нет и быть не может никаких сенсоров... Не, какой-нибудь эмулятор может их эмулировать, но зачем?

Comment: `Что делать?` — ничего. нет доступа к реальному железу. напишите в microsoft с изложением ваших хотелок. может быть даже что-нибудь вам и ответят. и даже вежливо.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, учитывая, что WSL2 - это уже не транслятор всех вызовов, как v1, а тупо виртуалка как kvm, то очень сильно сомневаюсь, что будут добавлять проброс.